# Plugin system security in .NET Framework 4.x (without CAS)

Tags: c#, .net, security, plugins, permissions

What I'd like to achieve is a plugin system with the following features:

- loading external plugins, from sources potentially not trusted by me (the developer), but trusted by the end-user who installed the plugin
- granting per-plugin permissions within a specific scope; e.g. one plugin may have a permission to read files from a specific location, while others may be allowed to connect to specific website location
- a special case of per-plugin permissions: interacts with another object, most likely provided as an interface instance, without accessing any of its non-public members (not even with sneaky Reflection techniques)
- prevention of actions the end-user didn't agree to, such as accessing non-public members or operating on the filesystem, before the plugin code can do any harm

During my search, I've mostly found SO solutions involving Code Access Security which, as far as I know, is outdated as of .NET 4.x. I've also read up a bit on the new security model on MSDN pages, and it seems [library code that exposes protected resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/secure-coding-guidelines#library-code-that-exposes-protected-resources) will be necessary here; however, I could not find any examples showing how to apply such code. My guess is that it'll involve creating separate AppDomains and possibly playing around with Principal permissions, but that's about as far as my knowledge gets.

On a side note, I've also found mentions of requiring strongly named assemblies only, but I'm not convinced that'll be enough. If I'm not mistaken, one of the strong naming benefits is that the plugin developer can prove their own identity by signing the assembly hash with own private key, and others can check by using well-known and trusted public key. However, this alone seems too inflexible, as it either requires the developer to personally decide whose code should be trusted or just trust anyone who learned to sign their assembly.

I'll be very grateful for a good example of security management code using the most up-to-date security model. What I currently have in mind:

- an interface for service exposing potentially sensitive operations (say, A and B)
- a dummy implementation of the service, focusing on preventing the unauthorised execution of these operations
- two plugins from separate assemblies, one with permission to perform operation A and other with permission for operation B
- an application that sets up the service, loads the assemblies with plugins and tries to perform operations for each of these, so that unauthorised operations are blocked and authorised operations are executed correctly
- when run within the application, neither plugin on its own should be able to access general sensitive APIs, such as file I/O or networking, but it should be possible to do through the service
- all that while following [these recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/secure-coding-guidelines) as closely as feasible (as opposed to CAS-based solutions from SO questions back from year 2010)

Of course, you are welcome to suggest an alternative architecture, if it achieves the goal in a better way.

Comment: CAS by itself is not deprecated, however it's usage as a security boundary between trusted code (your application) and untrusted (plugin) is discouraged. As far as I understand, that's because MS doesn't want to develop it futher and won't fix any vulnerabilities which allow to bypass it. They list "alternative measures" you can use if you are going to execute unknown code in section "Securing Resource Access" in article you linked. There is no "replacement" for CAS in this regard (as a mentioned security boundary).

Comment: Are the plugins required to be written in C# (or rather are there any language constraints for the plugins)?

Comment: In general I assume .NET assemblies, compatible with the main application's .NET version, would be supported as plugins (whether written in C# or VB or other .NET-compiling language). I don't have plans to directly support other libraries; if someone would want to plug one in, they'd need to make a .NET-based interface for it.

Comment: While it doesn't solve the core of your problem, I think OIDC Hybrid Flow might be worth looking into as a means to get fine-grained control over which plugins can access which APIs. You can apply scopes to the relevant parts of your API surface and assign claims to plugins based on their access level. Whatever strong-signing or similar infrastructure you end up going with, could provide the basis for authentication while the claims and scopes then handle the specifics of what exactly a plugin is allowed to do.

Comment: CAS is not depricated as stated by @Evk. I don't think it will ever be decrecated as .net framework itself heavily uses it. It is just that msft doesn't recommend it now for sandboxing. Nevertheless I have created an application which uses CAS for sandboxing with similar requirement as yours. I know apps which uses it. For example Bloomberg has a platform called "AppPortal" which uses CAS to achieve sandboxing. I'm happy to provide solution with CAS if you would like to use it.

Comment: I suppose some extra solution won't hurt. It'd be good to have some explanation why the proposed CAS-using solution provides a better sandboxing than, say, plainly spawning an AppDomain and setting its permissions.

Comment: What about running it as restricted user, Then you have extremely limited access both for your program and plugins. Then in your plugin Interface you add function for local and network IO. Then when you access those you run the request as another user using impersonation.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is hard on multiple levels.

Closest thing I've seen to this is a long forgotten Microsoft project called [Terrarium](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/LearningOpportunityNETTerrariumIsBack.aspx), where you code a creature using a .net language, build  it, and submit your assembly containing your creature to live on a terrarium server which was written in .NET 1.0. It was a challenge for MS developers to create an environment where any user can run code but be secure and play nice. They created a tool to ban certain types to be used in assembly. It is called [AsmCheck](http://Terrarium/Client/AsmCheck/asmcheck.cpp).

I had tried to achieve same thing using app domains in past without much success.

From time to time I still think about what is the best way to achieve such task. It is possible, Android and iOS works like that, but it requires me to write entire OS or framework as best.

I've planned to create an AppDomain and load my plugin loader to this domain. Loader then loads the plugin assembly and all the assemblies it tries to load  by hijacking assembly loader. When loading an assembly it uses AsmCheck.vNext to check if it does something shady. For every assembly it loaded, it uses an IoC container (like [this](https://github.com/philiplaureano/Deflector.NET)) to limit access to framework.

Verification of assemblies is done on my side by checking strong names with my plugin registry, or checking certificates for code signing.

All seems good until you see Confuser or its successor [ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx). It creates proxy types to access methods by converting method to self initializing static delegates that references methods not by name but a reference id. Now, how can I possibly analyse and/or limit access to this.

Or you can prevent System.IO namespace altogether and provide you own IO library, but how can you limit one to use PInvoke and call GetProcAddress so it can access ReadFile, WriteFile, etc...

Just way too many cases to handle, and this is only the tip of the iceberg. If you absolutely have to limit plugins to do stuff you have to write you own framework or provide a scripting language like lua.

You can try App Containerization. Every plugin is loaded in a special container and talks to your app to perform tasks that require permissions. Other than that, code running in container think container is the whole computer.

One day I'd like to see someone solve this problem in a simple and efficient way.

PS: My answer is not an answer. It is an answer because it just does not fit in a comment.

Comment: I think @edokan is correct in that using a "container VM" mechanism is the best way today. You could develop a system that runs Docker images which contain the plugin's, and have an API layer to perform the communication between your main application and the Docker container-ized plugin. Of course, this is a big endeavor to tackle but in this day and age, the tools are available to make it happen.

Comment: Yeah, when I got push in the direction of "container VM", I searched a bit and Docker was quite prominently mentioned. One thing I'm concerned about is whether the application will run right off the bat on Windows 7+, provided the appropriate .NET framework version is installed. It seems Docker isn't included in Windows 7, although maybe there's a way to ship it somehow with the application...?

Answer (score 3):

You can force plugins to run in separate process and interact with your application only using RPC.
This way they won´t have access on anything except you provided through API.

Android operating system does same thing to expose functionality for Applications Look [IBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I might look into that in my free time. From what little I've seen, RPC seems to be for client-server applications, and I assume Application+API would be the "server" layer and Proxy+Plugin would be one of "clients", right? A few questions, then: 1) How do I setup RPC connection within a context of a logically single application? 2) Can I ensure that application refers to plugin code in a synchronous manner (i.e. call from app to plugin and plugin executing its logic is uninterrupted)? 3) What would be the overhead of such RPC call?

Comment: @Alice 

1) and 3) You can run each plugin in separate process and use shared memory to communicate between processes which is very fast. In windows os you can use named pipes or you can write your own  custom pipe like this guy did and had kind of same requirements https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLX1sYVf-Xg 

2) I don't fully understand that question, what kind of interuption are you talking about ? can you provide more details

Comment: Thanks for the video, I'm going to check that out. As for 2), in hindsight I guess I meant the code being ran immediately rather than uninterrupted. E.g., if I call a local non-async method DoSomething(), its execution will begin immediately. On the other hand, if I call DoSomething() method on some server (WCF, HTTP, I dunno), it will queue the request before handling it and passing the result. So, I would like to know if RPC, performed by the main application spawning multiple processes, will act "immediately" like the local method or in "queued" manner like the server method.

Comment: @Alice That depends on your implementation of RPC transport layer, HTTP does so because It is designed by default like that. If you use Pipes (communication by shared memory between processes), you can  design to run method  immediately or asynchronously.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. One more question: how would I prevent the plugin process from performing sensitive operations of its own? Would I spawn a restrictive AppDomain for it, or...?

Comment: Unfortunately in windows you can only restrict access  per-user, not per-application process (plugin). so If it´s enough AppDomain will do the job.